# Axios posting to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

Here is the method I am using on the CreatePage.vue page

```
  methods: {
async createPost() {
  try {
    await PostService.createPost(this.form);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
  }
};
```

Here is the PostService class

```
   const axios = require('axios')
   const url = 'api/post/'

class PostService {
static async createPost(post) {
    return axios.post(url + 'create', post)
}

}
```

And here is the vue.config for proxy

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/public'),
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        }
    }
},
}
```

When I make a post request which should go to 
    http://localhost:3000/api/post/create

The issue is it appends the current pages address to the beginning of the request, for example,
    http://localhost:3000/posts/api/post/create 
(posts page, would append dashboard if on dashboard page)

Comment: const url = '/api/post/'

Comment: The URL needs a leading slash to use the root of the host as base instead of the current page, so `const url = '/api/post/'`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your PostService class because you did not include "/" in the URL, change that to

```
const axios = require('axios')
const url = '/api/post/'

class PostService {
  static async createPost(post) {
    return axios.post(url + 'create', post)
  }
}
``
```